# Custom RatingBar doesn't work on Dialog

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-dialog, ratingbar

I have set my custom RatingBar Style

Inside style.xml this is my code:

```
<item name="android:ratingBarStyle">@style/RatingBarStyle</item>
<style name="RatingBarStyle" parent="android:Widget.RatingBar">
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/ratingbar</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">13dip</item>
    <item name="android:maxHeight">13dip</item>
</style>
```

now I have created a custom layout for a Dialog (Xml) [is inside a relativelayout]:

```
<RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/custom_dialog_vota_ratingbar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/custom_dialog_vota_label_ratingbar"
    android:layout_below="@+id/custom_dialog_vota_label_ratingbar"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:max="5"
    android:numStars="5"
    android:stepSize="0.5" />
```

and on my class I have this code:

```
public void onClick(View view) {
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(mContext);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog_vota);
            dialog.setTitle("Vota");
            String t = ((TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.custom_dialog_vota_label_ratingbar)).getText().toString();
            ((TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.custom_dialog_vota_label_ratingbar)).setText(t + nome_book);
            dialog.show();
        }
```

Now my RatingBar works fine everywhere, but on this dialog it doesn't work and I have no idea why..
Please help me

**EDIT** I don't know why it doesn't work on emulator but on preview in IDE totally works!

**EDIT2** So this is my result:
How you can see my custom RatingBar works on Listview or On other activity like this:
[image: it works]

but on my dialog it doesn't, and already tried to upload to my device, but still nothing..
[image: it doesn't work]

Sorry for "blur" but can't show (working in a office) my wip app..

Comment: Run it on an actual device and see if it works as intended. If not, post the incorrect image.

Comment: @Kai done! upload images, already tried to run on my device but nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use an AlertDialogBuilder you can set the style XML resource for the dialog. Then you can use a LayoutInflator to inflate your custom view and call setView on the builder